# Trim a vector by suitable matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find a matrix $A$ for which $Ax=(x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1})$, where $x$ is an $n$-vector. Be sure to specify the size of $A$ and all its entries.

I am a bit confused since $Ax\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times (n-2)}$ but $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ (or maybe $x\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$ if we consider $x$ as a row vector).I do not really know how the sizes of $A$ and $x$ can fit in order to produce a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{1\times (n-2)}$.

Case 1) Suppose $x$ is a column vector, i.e., $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$.

Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}^{a\times n}$. Then $Ax\in\mathbb{R}^{a\times 1}$.

Case 2) Suppose $x$ is a row vector, i.e., $x\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$. Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}^{a\times 1}$, then $Ax\in\mathbb{R}^{a\times n}$.

In both case, $Ax\notin\mathbb{R}^{1\times (n-2)}$.

**EDIT** (due to the comments):

Supposing that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{(n-2)\times n}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, which implies that $Ax\in\mathbb{R}^{n-2}$, I get that matrix $A$ needs to have entries
$$
a_{i,j}=\begin{cases}1, & i=1,2,\ldots,n-2\textrm{ and }j=i+1\\0, & \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Ax is meant to be a column vector.

Comment: Is it multiplication or some other kind of operator??

Comment: If $A$ is $n-2$ by $n$ and x is $n$ by 1 then it works.  Sometimes books write column vectors as rows in order to save space

Comment: Have you tried this for $n=3$?

Comment: @CyclotomicField Yes, for $n=3$, I get the matrix $A=(0,1,0)$.

Comment: @Rhjg ok. Now can you do $n=4$? You can probably guess what it is from there.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I already wrote down my solution in the edit of my question. Have you seen it?